# How to use api.add_resource to route in different files?

Tags: python, flask-restful

I have a routing table in `apis.py` using `flask-restful` like:

```
api.add_resource(sonarqube.SonarqubeHistory, '/sonarqube/<project_name>')
api.add_resource(project.ProjectFile, '/project/<sint:project_id>/file')
api.add_resource(redmine.RedmineFile, '/download', '/file/<int:file_id>')
```

The resource classes are in other modules like `sonarqube.py`, `project.py`, or `redmine.py`.

My question is: Is that possible to also move `api.add_resource()` into the other modules (For more structured code)? I tried simply move the statement and `from apis import api`, but since `apis.py` also do other works it will result circular import.

Is there an example for similar use cases?

Answer (score 0):

Actually for better design, split the routing table into different module from apis.py, as apis.py is also doing other work. For example routingapis.py.

Import the new "routingapis" where ever required.

If still circular imports noticed and unavoidable even after splitting, then defer importing. Write a separate function for adding the resource

something like

```
def functionToAddResource():
   from routingapis import api
   api.add_resource(sonarqube.SonarqubeHistory, '/sonarqube/<project_name>')
```

Comment: In this case, how do I pass the `app` instance to `routingapis.py`? (Since creating `API` instance requires `app`)

Comment: You should have the app object available if designed appropriately. Please follow this design https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/ .